# how do I merge the datasets and then create a line graph with two lines and a secondary axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, line

I am looking at the relationship between unemployment and earnings by local authority, and what to merge the two datasets so that I can then create a line graph showing their relationship with a secondary axis.

How would i do this?

Currently my code is below but it is not working:

```
ggplot(u_e , aes(x=date, y=unemploymentrate))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(y=medianearnings)
```

I have two datasets, one for earnings and one for unemployment which look like this:

```
  localauthority      `median earnings` year     
  <chr>                           <dbl> <chr>    
1 Aberdeen City                    532. 2010/2011
2 Aberdeenshire                    545. 2010/2011
3 Angus                            460. 2010/2011
4 Argyll & Bute                    468. 2010/2011
5 Clackmannanshire                 459. 2010/2011
6 Dumfries & Galloway              450. 2010/2011

  localauthority        `unemployment rate` year     
  <chr>                               <dbl> <chr>    
1 Aberdeenshire                         3.6 2010/2011
2 Aberdeen City                         5.3 2010/2011
3 Angus                                 6.7 2010/2011
4 Argyll and Bute                       6.4 2010/2011
5 Clackmannanshire                      8.3 2010/2011
6 Dumfries and Galloway                 6.5 2010/2011
```

Comment: Can you share a sample data using the `dput` function on your datasets? Also, you are using `date` in your code, but I don't see any `date` variable in your datasets.

Comment: In addition to sharing a dataset (what you have shared seems not to be the complete one and also lacks some columns indicatedin the `ggplot` code), can you clarify what you are looking to produce in the combined line graph?  If you have a date on the x axis and y axis (axes) are the values, how did you want to capture the local authority... or did you?  Hard to make recommendations without the full dataset, where considerations such as how many `u_e$localauthority` entries are there... I would also recommend considering comparing the two with one axis, like comparing growth % of each.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `full_join` from the dplyr package.

Make sure that the Local Authority names match! There are 'and' and '&' used interchangeably and these need to be consistent to merge the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

earnings <- read.csv("~/bin/example_problems_datasets/median_earnings.csv")
unemployment <- read.csv("~/bin/example_problems_datasets/unemployment.csv", header = T)

dat <- earnings %>% full_join(unemployment, by = "localauthority")

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = unemploymentrate, y = medianearnings)) +
  geom_line()
```